# Why the risc-v instruction "addi sp,sp,-32" is converted to binary code "11 01"?

Tags: assembly, riscv, instruction-encoding

I'm learning risc-v instruction set. I know that "addi sp,sp,-40" will be converted to "fd810113". But I don't know why "addi sp,sp,-32" is converted to binary code "11 01".

[image]

Comment: That's hexadecimal not binary.  Don't be tricked by the fact that >that< number is only using the (hex) digits `0` and `1`.

Comment: That "code" at main looks like data, not instructions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is using the compressed instruction format:

`C.ADDI[2:0] nzimm[5] dest[4:0] nzimm[4:0] C1[1:0]`

With `C.ADDI` being `000`, `SP` being register #2 and `C1` being `01` it gives:

`000 1 00010 00000 01 = 0001 0001 0000 0001 = 0x1101`

Note that the compressed instruction only takes immediate from -32 to +31 due to having 6 bits of space which is why the other instruction with -40 is using the 32 bit format.

Comment: Side note: The `addi sp, sp, -64` instruction is translated into `c.addi16sp`. This instructions requires the immediate to be a multiple of 16, which is why `addi sp, sp, -64` can be compressed whereas `addi sp, sp, -40` can't.

Comment: That's only for the case mentioned by @Lindydancer though.